# Cake slicing problem for irrational angles

Tags: geometry, puzzle

I came across the  following question

*"A person plays the following game with a cake.
He cuts a piece forming a circular sector of x degrees and flips the piece upside down, with the icing on the bottom.
He then rotates the cake by x degrees counterclockwise, cuts an adjacent x degree piece and flips it upside down.
He keeps repeating this, until after a total of N steps, all the icing is back on top.
Amazingly, this works for any piece size, even if the cutting angle is an irrational number: all the icing will be back on top after a finite number of steps"*

I understand why this must be true for any x being any rational number(https://simomaths.wordpress.com/2013/02/08/thoughts-on-a-problem-iii/)  but can someone explain how this can be achieved for x being irrational ?

for example if x = 360/sqrt(60) how can N.x be a multiple of 360 degrees

Comment: Your link covers this. In particular "cutting lines may repeat even though the positions at which you cut don’t, since the cutting lines themselves aren’t stationary." You are correct that if $x$ is irrational then $nx$ is never a multiple of $360$.

Comment: This is Project Euler problem 566, the current one.

Comment: @Empy2: this is not a project Euler problem. It is a classical puzzle which dates back to some russian olympiad problem. The Project Euler problem you state is a generalization of this. Understanding the solution for one angle is not enough for providing the answer to the Project Euler problem.

Comment: Even if it were enough, I don't see why this being related to some Project Euler problem would prevent people from investigating this further.

Comment: @BeniBogosel Project Euler doesn't want people to publish solutions of problems (with exception of the first 100 introductory problems.

Comment: @BeniBogosel On their website FAQ they say "It appears that you have answered your own question. There is nothing quite like that "Aha!" moment when you finally beat a problem which you have been working on for some time. It is often through the best of intentions in wishing to share our insights so that others can enjoy that moment too. Sadly, that will rarely be the case for your readers. Real learning is an active process and seeing how it is done is a long way from experiencing that epiphany of discovery. Please do not deny others what you have so richly valued yourself."

Comment: @SomeGuy: I re-iterate my remark. The problem as stated above is NOT the Project Euler problem 566. It is a simpler case. The problem is classical and is not the property of Project Euler. While some might think that working a lot on a problem until you get it right is the right way to go, others just want to learn the key trick and move on. Some classes of Project Euler problems cannot be solved unless you see and understand the solution to one of them.

Comment: @BeniBogosel Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. I thought you were saying "So what if it is a Project Euler problem?" but that was clearly not your intention.